# nicEditor and onchange event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, nicedit

I have used More than 5 nicEditors in my application.Below is my **code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('single_answer_description')
            )
        );
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('multiple_answer_description')
            )
        );
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('drag_words_paragraph')

            )
        );
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){
        var myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
        myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
            alert("m");
        });
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('drop_words_paragraph')
            )
        );
    });

});
```

In that I want to add onchange event with drag_words_paragraph textarea.onchange of text it will add in one div..I tried like this

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){
    var myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
    myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
    // Your code here that is called whenever the user blurs (stops editing) the nicedit instance
    });
});
```

But I can't get exact result instead im getting error removeInstance() is not a function.Please anyone help me.I am struggling for this errorlongtime.Thanks in advance

Comment: might be to do with the way you're defining `.panelInstance`s http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events sometimes you do it as a string and sometimes as a DOM object. Your `drag_words_paragraph` paragraph instance looks okay, but less certain about your others. What happens if you define them all as ID strings?

Comment: Can U explain In code.I didn't get your point

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" name="drag_words_paragraph" id="drag_words_paragraph" ></textarea> for this textarea I added nicEditor with above code

Comment: for example `new nicEditor().panelInstance(
            document.getElementById('single_answer_description')
        )` looks like it should just be `new nicEditor().panelInstance(
           'single_answer_description'
        )` according to the niceedit wiki

Comment: Okie then How can I add onchange event in this part.By the way I type Something it will add in new Div

Comment: I guess the first question is, if you implement this throughout do you still get the same error? if not and if your blur event listener still doesn't work then consider using the jquery 'blur' detect directly in your textarea input. http://api.jquery.com/blur/ along with jquery append to add new div's. I'm on mobile at the moment so will format a better response later if no one else does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134476/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-sam0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are declare new PaneInstance for same ID more than once.

try changing your code as below

```
//declare a global variable to store the editor text
var drag_words_paragraph;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // assign the text to variable
    window.drag_words_paragraph = $('#drag_words_paragraph').text();    

    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('single_answer_description')
            )
        );
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            new nicEditor().panelInstance(
                document.getElementById('multiple_answer_description')
            )
        );
    });
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.editors.push(
            var myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
             myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
                  debugger;
                  var text = this.instanceById('drag_words_paragraph').getContent();
                  if (window.drag_words_paragraph == text) {
                    //Text has not been changed
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    //Text has been changed
                    //You can call your functions here.
                    alert('text changed');

                    window.drag_words_paragraph = text;
                  }
                });
            )
        );
    });
```

Your code seems to be working.

As commented by `Richard Welsh` in this http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events

Check the snippet below based on his workaround.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#drag_words_paragraph_text').text($('#drag_words_paragraph').text());

  var myInstance = new nicEditor({
    iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
  }).panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
  myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
    debugger;
    var hiddenElem = $('#drag_words_paragraph_text');
    var text = this.instanceById('drag_words_paragraph').getContent();
    if ($(hiddenElem).text() == text ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('text changed');
      $(hiddenElem).text(text);
    }
  });

});

function changeText(){
  var newText = $('#change_text').val();
  nicEditors.findEditor('drag_words_paragraph').setContent(newText);
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEdit.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" name="drag_words_paragraph" id="drag_words_paragraph">
  Some random text
</textarea>

<div style="display:none" id="drag_words_paragraph_text"></div>
<br/>

<textarea id="change_text" placeholder="enter some text here" ></textarea>

<button id="change_text_btn" onclick="changeText();">change text</button>
```

Comment: I tried this code.. What is happening Wherever I click it showing alert.I cant select anything from dropdown

Comment: It will alert only after typing in nicEditor..Got my Issue right?

Comment: Why are you adding this select dropdown

Comment: its simply added for testing.. to show you that when you change text and click on other elements you wont get alerts..(as you said `Wherever I click it showing alert.I cant select anything from dropdown` in your previous comment ) you can remove it completely..

Comment: Im getting this error "nicEdit.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: A.removeInstance is not a function"

Comment: The error is may be because you are trying to add a `new PanelInstance` multiple times.. when the Instance with the id `drag_words_paragraph` already exists.. no need to add `new`

Comment: in your code you have used `new nicEditor().panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');` more than once on document ready. which is not requird

Comment: That's okay. I want to add the same content to another div onchange anything in second div.Because If I change anything in below div and I click outside it automatically change the content in nicEditor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134551/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-karthikeyan-vedi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('.nicEdit-main').addEventListener("input", function(e) {
   console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
}, false);
```